# How to extract the body part of a function?

Tags: php

The function extractBody() extracts the body part of a function:

```
$data = '
    <?php 
    function my_function($param){
        if($param === true){
            // This is true
        }else if($param === false){
            // This is false
        }else{
            // This is not
        }
    }
    ?>
';

function extractBody($functionName, $data) {
    $c = preg_match_all("/function\s+".$functionName."\s*\((?<param>[^\)]*)\)\s*(?<body>\{(?:[^{}]+|(?&body))*\})/", $data, $matches);
    return $c > 0 ? $matches['body'] : null;
}


$body =extractBody("my_function", $data);

var_dump($body);
```

result: The variable `$body` contains

```
 if($param === true){
            // This is true
        }else if($param === false){
            // This is false
        }else{
            // This is not
        }
```

Now I need a second function to work with lambda functions (function is assigned to a variable)

```
$data2 = '
    <?php 
    $my_function = function($param){
        if($param === true){
            // This is true
        }else if($param === false){
            // This is false
        }else{
            // This is not
        }
    }
    ?>
';

function extractBody2($functionName, $data) {
    $c = preg_match_all("/".$functionName."\s+=\s+function\s+\s*\((?<param>[^\)]*)\)\s*(?<body>\{(?:[^{}]+|(?&body))*\})/", $data, $matches);
    return $c > 0 ? $matches['body'] : null;
}


$body2 =extractBody2("my_function", $data2);

var_dump($body2);
```

Unfortunately, I'm not a regex specialist and I get NULL back.
I think the error must be somewhere here: `"/".$functionName."\s+=\s+`
regex101 didn't reveal any issues though.

Comment: Why not simply, in both cases, look for the first `{` and the last `}`? Anything in between, as long as it is a normal or lambda function, will be the function body. You don't always need to use a regular expression to solve these things, especially when your input, and output, is only a single function.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I don't know why OP needs to do this but this is more complex than it looks. I am sure it isn't as straightforward as just finding the first and the last brace. Usually string literals make it more cumbersome.

Comment: The reason I'm using a regex is because there might be other functions as well and I really just want to get the body back of a specific function.

Comment: @nice_dev: With [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) you can find the first `{`, and with [strrpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) you find the last `}`. Then all you need to do is get the body with [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ok but there are several assumptions being made like the code is syntatically correct, doesn't use arrow functions or only one function inside a code snippet etc.

Comment: @nice_dev: That's certainly true, but regular expression often also cannot cope with syntax errors. I simply went with what is being asked in the question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Fair enough. Now, OP's comment changes things.

Comment: Syntax errors can be ignored. Example code updated to make it more clear.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
function extractBody2($functionName, $data) {
    $c = preg_match_all("/\\$".$functionName."\s+=\s+function\s*\((?<param>[^\)]*)\)\s*(?<body>\{(?:[^{}]+|(?&body))*\})/", $data, $matches);
    return $c > 0 ? $matches['body'] : null;
}
```

Comment: Even [HTML shouldn't be parsed with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/285587)

Comment: It serves my purpose.

Comment: But surely you understand it's a very bad idea?

Comment: Is there another easy and short way to accomplish it without using an external library?

Comment: Looks like you don't. A pity.